# Inserting millions of Elements into a Binary Search Tree BST

Tags: c, tree, binary-search-tree

I have been trying to solve this issue for almost 3 days with no luck yet. I am trying to insert many elements is size of (5 million)of unsigned integer into a binary tree.

This code works fine when I limit the total elements to be inserted into 10K, however, it does not work when I set the total elements to be 5 million. 
I am running this code on my PC which has:

- Windows 7 - 32
- RAM 4 GB

Any help would be really appreciated. Thanks in advance :) 
Here is my code:

```css
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<stdio.h>

typedef int ElementType;

typedef struct TreeNode {
  ElementType element;
  struct TreeNode *left, *right;
} TreeNode;

TreeNode *createTree(){
    //Create the root of tree
    TreeNode *tempNode;
    tempNode = malloc(sizeof(TreeNode));
    tempNode->element = 0;
    tempNode->left = NULL;
    tempNode->right = NULL;
    return tempNode;
}

TreeNode *createNode(ElementType X){
    //Create a new leaf node and return the pointer
    TreeNode *tempNode;
    tempNode = malloc(sizeof(TreeNode));
    tempNode->element = X;
    tempNode->left = NULL;
    tempNode->right = NULL;
    return tempNode;
}

TreeNode *insertElement(TreeNode *node, ElementType X){
    //insert element to Tree
    if(node==NULL){
        return createNode(X);
    }
    else{
        if(X < node->element){
                node->left = insertElement(node->left, X);
                return node; // add this.
}
    else if(X > node->element){
                 node->right =  insertElement(node->right, X);
                 return node; // add t

        else if(X == node->element){
            printf("Oops! the element is already present in the tree.");
        }
    }
}

TreeNode *displayTree(TreeNode *node){
    //display the full tree
    if(node==NULL){
        return;
    }
    displayTree(node->left);
    printf("| %d ", node->element); 
    displayTree(node->right);
}

main(){
    //pointer to root of tree #2
    TreeNode *TreePtr;
    TreeNode *TreeRoot;
    TreeNode *TreeChild;

    //Create the root of tree
    TreePtr = createTree();

    TreeRoot = TreePtr;

    TreeRoot->element = 32;
    
  for ( int i=0; i < 5000000; i ++)
    insertElement(TreeRoot, i);
   
    displayTree(TreeRoot);
}
```

Any help would be really appreciated. Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Hard to say without knowing what error you're getting.  Since you're using recursion, depending on the sequence that the items are added, the recursion could cause stack overflow.  Since Binary Tree does not have to be balanced, inserting the items where data is mostly sorted already will lead to very deep and unbalanced tree and deep recursive calls will cause stack overflow.  If you can, try using a B-tree (balanced tree)

Comment: Why do you always insert the value eight (8)? As I see, you will always get a tree with only a key (eight)

Comment: It is actually a typo, it should be an " i"

Comment: "it does not work". That is never a valid problem description by itself. Please describe what the actual error or incorrect behaviour is.

Comment: it shows a message saying " stack overflow "..

Comment: ^^ you think we didn't need to know that?  :((

Comment: PS: A code snippet isn't for c.  It's for html/css/js.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that you have no other errors in your code, always inserting 8 will degenerate the tree to a list, and I think, your stack will overflow at some recursion level far below the 5 million.

To generally avoid a degenerated tree, I would advise you to use the insert/deletion semantics of an AVL-Tree.
This has the advantage, that your datastructures can remain as they are, but you only have to adapt the insert and delete procedures.

Edit: In your comment, you state now that you do not insert always 8 but i. This means, you insert pre-sorted elements into the binary tree, which also degenerates it to a list, so the same problem arises as with always inserting "8".

It looks like:

```
1
 \
  2
   \
    3
     \
      4
       \
       ...
```

after inserting the elements in order.
An AVL-Tree will not suffer from that problem:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AVL_tree

Comment: Without wishing to be controversial, I think you're wrong, because @Faisal prevents insertion of duplicates

Comment: He inserts the elements in sorted order, which results in the same phenomenon, as I wrote below (see section Edit:)

Comment: I have read: " always inserting 8 will degenerate the tree to a list"

Answer (score 1):

OK Faisal.

If you insert the value of `i`, then you will always insert a key greater than all the keys currently contained in the tree. Consequently you will get a tree of maximum height, which in performance (and shape too) is equivalent to a list. Since you algorithm is recursive, you will get a stack overflow very quickly.

A possible way for dealing with you problem, but is not a guarantee for avoiding an overflow, is to insert random keys. Theoretically, the average on the number of nodes revised in an unsuccessful search is O(log N).

So you could use the `rand()` for getting random numbers or a more sophisticated and sure random number generator.